# Recover mysql database from ib_logfile, ibdata files

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have a mysql database, and today I woke up and noticed that some of my tables are empty (like if they were truncated) but some aren't. This is not an SQL injection since I took care of that, but still haven't figured out what really happened.

Now I need to recover that data that was deleted, but the only thing I have are the lib files, so, is there a way to recover a database data using those files? We never deleted any file.

Basically I have ib_logfile, ibdata files but I never enabled Binary Logging.

Comment: The files ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 and ibdata1 *are* the InnoDB database. InnoDB will handle crash recovery when it is started. if `innodb_file_per_table` option is (was) enabled when the tables were created, then each table will have it's own ibd tablespace/datafile. But we don't even know that these "now empty" tables use the InnoDB storage engine... so we can't really make a recommendation.  Restoring a copy of a database from a previous point in time requires us to have a "backup" of the database available.

Comment: the problem is that some tables were suddenly empty, I do not know what happened, it is really weird, even some records were created at the same time and other tables are completely empty. So I am lost and worried about what to do now